# Launching Ubuntu18.04 on wsl in is very slow

Tags: 18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

launching ubuntu 18.04 has become very slow on my machine . I guess it is a problem with this specific distribution Ubuntu18.04, because I have installed other distribution Ubuntu 20.4, Kali, Debian. They all launch quickly.

how do I fix this slowness and make it fast as it used to be ?

I have zsh and oh-my-zsh installed in Ubuntu, I tried to disable them and use bash only, the startup was relatively quicker but it is still slow compared to what it used to be

### Windows Build Number

Version 20H2 (OS Build 19042.928)

### WSL Version

WSL 1

### Distro Version

Ubuntu 18.04

Windows Terminal
Version: 1.7.1033.0

Answer (score 0):

You mention you are using WSL1. In general, performance of WSL2 should be better for operations on the root filesystem (i.e. not-NTFS/Windows drives). Conversely, WSL1 has much better performance when working with files on NTFS drives.

Also, for WSL1, I recommend adding an exclusion to Windows Security.  *Start Menu* -> *Windows Security* -> *Virus & Threat Protection* -> *Manage Settings* -> *Add or Remove Exclusions*, and add the `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Packages\<distro>` folder.  That can make a pretty big difference with WSL1 performance, in my experience.